# Why does CompareInfo.IndexOf() not ignore the symbols in this code?

Tags: linux, windows, .net-core, cultureinfo

I am doing an outcome comparison between .NET Core on Windows and on Linux (Ubuntu 18.04). In string comparison, I'm seeing different outcomes. When running the following code snippet, I get `0` on Windows and `-1` on Linux. My understanding of this code is that the `♪` character should be ignore and the remaining "Mary" should match.

I've tried using `CurrentCulture`, `InvariantCulture`, multiple `CompareOptions` - they all return -1 on Linux.

While going through the `CompareInfo` source code [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/mscorlib/system/globalization/compareinfo.cs#L1386), it points to the use of `FindNLSStringEx` which I understand to be a [Q/Invoke to the kernel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winnls/nf-winnls-findnlsstringex). If that's true, how does Linux handle this code? Is there any way to get Linux to return `0` here?

```cs
System.Globalization.CompareInfo info = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.CompareInfo;
int index = info.IndexOf("Mary", "♪Mary", System.Globalization.CompareOptions.IgnoreSymbols);
System.Console.WriteLine(index);
```

Comment: I'd say at the very least you can use `char.GetUnicodeCategory` to strip out symbols yourself. So clearly the `FindNLSStringEx` is a native function that directly supports a flag that filters out symbols. How can we find out what the linux build is invoking? Is it just managed or is there an equivalent linux function that does not support filtering out symbol characters?

Comment: I think you should raise an issue on the .net core GitHub. This sounds like a bug to me. How can we trust .net core to make cross platform apps if string comparison is different?

Comment: I raised an issue on github, and they've responded: https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/37526

Essentially, this is a problem at the ICU level as I suspected and not the CoreClr.